# minimize $|x^a-y^b|$ over $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$

Tags: number-theory

I am interested in the following quantity for various real (or complex) values of $x$ and $y$:

$$f(x,y) = \inf\{|x^a - y^b |: a \text{ and } b \in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$$

Is there a general formula known for $f(x,y)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: I doubt there's a general formula even for $x,y$ integers. Finding $f(x,y)$ for a particular pair of integers can be a difficult problem to solve.

Comment: what happens when $\frac{a}{b} \rightarrow \frac{\ln y}{\ln x}$?

Comment: @TheoBendit This is false; for example for $f(\tfrac12,\tfrac13)=0$. In fact if $|x|,|y|<1$ then $f(x,y)=0$ as $x^a$ and $y^b$ both tend to $0$ as $a$ and $b$ tend to infinity.

Comment: @Servaes Good point.